Should 'a' or 'an' be used when referring to a mathematical usage of a parameter *n*?
I would like to state, in a different way, a sentence with the meaning:

Consider a matrix whose dimensions are n×n ....

For a quick context, the letter n simply represents a mathematical value (a certain parameter or a number). I would like to rephrase it. Considering "n" as a word with a single letter, its first (and only) letter 'n' starts with a consonant letter, which means I should write:

Consider a n×n matrix...

However, it is pronounced like "en", which makes the combination "a en by en matrix..." seem unnatural (And 'e' is a vowel...). So should it be:

Consider an n×n matrix...


Did you try searching? There are a lot of similar questions e.g. on acronyms and initialisms, XML, X-ray, etc.

The a/an-choice is (or should be) driven solely by how the whole is read out. Others may not agree with this, but I even prefer 'a NP' because I invariably expand to 'noun phrase' on reading out. But with 'an n×n matrix' there's only one choice.

This question is similar to: Does one use 'a' or 'an' before the word X-Ray?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also, for an overview, When should I use a vs an?.
